# Assign included JS function to AngularJS scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I am including a function from my webserver, and I need to include this existing function to my AngulerJS scope so I can use it in my view. I have tried this:

```
$scope.getSymbolName = get_symbol_name
```

`get_symbol_name()` is the function I have included.

I am getting this error:

```
Can't interpolate: {{getSymbolName(9)}}
```

What am I doing wrong?

View code:

```
<span style="width:100px;display:inline-block;">
   {{getSymbolName(trade.symbol_id)}} <br />
   Inleg: &euro;{{trade.amount_open}}
</span>
```

Comment: Can you show the view code?

Comment: What exactly do you want to see? I have included a JS file from an extern server, and I just want to assign it to my $scope in controllers.js. There is no code really to show.

Comment: i believe @Paul is referring to the template (the html), as the interpolation message originates from the view.

Comment: Oh, my bad. I'll update my question.

Comment: it appears that `get_symbol_name` is not a function (or undefined), how are you injecting that variable?

Comment: Oh, my bad. I was injecting that with the code I tried. Failed AJAX requests caused the problem... its solved now.

Answer (score 0):

```
<span style="width:100px;display:inline-block;">
   {{get_symbol_name(trade.symbol_id)}} <br />
   Inleg: &euro;{{trade.amount_open}}
</span>
```

your function like this

```
$scope.get_symbol_name=function(id){
   return id;
}
```